What should <InstallLocation> be when I import previously exported WSL distro?
I want to clone a distro.
When I installed Ubuntu in WSL2 and Windows 11, using the canonical guide. At no point did I need to specify where to install it. It just installed it.
Maybe its in this folder:
C:\Users%username%\AppData\Local\Packages\MicrosoftCorporationII.WindowsSubsystemForLinux_8wekyb3d8bbwe>
I discovered the distro is mounted a virtual disk \wsl.localhost\Ubuntu-24.04
Now want to 'clone' the distro with:
wsl.exe --export <DistributionName> <FileName>
wsl.exe --import <DistributionName> <InstallLocation> <FileName>.

What should the  be? Do I need to create and mount a virtual disk?

Using the export and import command is how you do it. Are you looking to clone the configuration or mount the ext4 virtual hdd of the WSL instance. I am avoiding the term VM because it’s not actually a VM.

I am looking to clone the config, which I did to c:\ubuntu as the InstallLocation as I could not work out where the original's InstallLocation was. It boots fine and mounted a new virtual disk as a clone of the exported one.

Export doesn’t require a file location, Windows, is aware of the instance location. Import is the file location of the archive that is created. Which is whatever path you give to the Export command. I guess my confusion is. What’s the question?

I clarified the question with an Edit. Its the  that I am unsure what to set it to. The  includes a path to the export and that much is clear.
